# Read JavaScript variable value in PHP function, also everything happens in script section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

> [image: Blockquote]

I know it's impossible, but I want to read dictionary value to pass Php function, do you have any idea how to replace

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client's browser. That will always happen AFTER the page has left the server, where some PHP functionality might have been used to compose the page in the first place. If you want to pass something from JavaScript to PHP you should look at AJAX and related methods.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and explanation. this dictionary value is also ajax method's result. Ah i guess, I can write the same ajax method which will invoke get_text() and return result which i need. Thank you for idea.